# Basic Arrays and loop Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a following sample code from my lecture note.

```
int[] a = new int[3]; 
a[0] = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {    
    a[i] = a[i-1] + i;
}
```

And I am assuming that this will return

```
[1,2,3]
```

after running the following code.

Because the loop starts from `1` and counts up to `3`. when the first loop gets executed i is assinged as `1` and `[1-1]+1` and the result is `1` and next `i` becomes `2` and result is `2.....`

I did not think `a[0]=1;`  was doing anything much. 
But I am not sure if that is correct.

Could and one tell me if my assumption is correct, please?

Comment: `a[i-1] + i != [1-1] + 1`... `a[i-1]` is 1 => `1 + i` is 2.

Comment: Revisit the second iteration through the loop step by step.  Also, `a[0]=1;` is an assignment of the first value in the array to the value 1, so make sure you take that into account when figuring out what is happening during each iteration.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see ecaxtly what each line of code does.

Comment: Because....I am not sure  why, but When I enter this code and try to compile it the error message comes up saying that "illegal character:\11 ".

Comment: @user1721548 do you have the needed `class Main { public static void main(String[] args) {  /* your code */ }}` around your code?

Comment: brimborium I did not realise that I needed to used the main method. Now I can apply it to others. So thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, not exactly:

```
i   |   a[i-1]    | a[i] = a[i-1] + i
----+-------------+------------------
1   |  a[0] = 1   | a[1] = 1 + 1 = 2
2   |  a[1] = 2   | a[2] = 2 + 2 = 4
```